# directory for portable app (Fiji)

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the .zip of Fiji from [its web](http://fiji.sc/#download), and then I extracted the files to my `$HOME` directory. I can run it correctly when running the executable file. However, I think that this is not a well suited directory, and I would like to know where would be the best place to move it.

I read in some posts that portable apps may be installed at /opt, but I am not sure that it would be my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an objectively chosen place to put portable apps. They are portable, after all.

The best thing to do with any portable app is to move it and its files into a directory and put that directory somewhere you know it won't be accidentally deleted. Definitely do not keep it in Downloads, especially if you regularly delete items from there.

If you want it to be easily accessible, put the folder containing the app on your desktop. It probably won't be accidentally deleted, and it'll be right there to click on. You can even make a link to the executable if you want even more convenience. You could also put the folder in your documents.

As far as I know, Ubuntu doesn't have designated space for portable apps. Just put them where they won't be removed.

Comment: Ok, but my question was more oriented to "how can i do to run it automatically when I type "Fiji" on the terminal, or when I want another program to call without passing the desktop or other directory URL.

Comment: @Jalo You'll have to add it as a PATH variable.